# Strange stdClass as array error when the variable seems to be an array, not an object

Tags: php, arrays, stdclass

**Something I noticed which patches the problem:** 
If I return `$this->_data` instead of `$this->_data[0]` - and then use `$object->data()[0]`, it does work as expected... However, I would like to return the [0] in the function.

Before you start saying that this is a duplicate - this question is unlike most other questions regarding this error.

I'm getting the following error when trying to access `$this->_data[0]` in my class:

`Cannot use object of type stdClass as array`

This is the function/line the error is being triggered on:

```
  public function data(){
      return $this->_data[0]; //<- line 75
  }
```

To my understanding, this error occurs when I try to use an object as I would use an array. However, when I `var_dump($this->_data)`, I get the following result:

```
array(1) {
    [0]=> object(stdClass)#34 (10) { 
        ["uid"]=> string(1) "0"
        ["nid"]=> string(3) "374"
        ["id"]=> string(8) "YicnaxYw"
        ["txt_content"]=> NULL
        ["path"]=> string(32) "/uploads/images/png/YicnaxYw.png"
        ["image"]=> string(1) "1"
        ["timestamp"]=> string(10) "1448192959"
        ["file_ext"]=> string(3) "png"
        ["file_type"]=> string(9) "image/png"
        ["originalFilename"]=> string(23) "2015-11-22_12-49-17.png"
    }
}
```

Where clearly this variable is of type `array(1)` with a `[0]` element ..

Could someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

@Xeli `$this->_data[0]->nid` causes the same error

**Fatal error**:  Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in **/home3/ramzes/includes/classes/UploadItem.php** on line **75**

`UploadItem.php:75`

```
  public function data(){
      return $this->_data[0]->nid;
  }
```

`$this->_data[0]` is a `fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)` object with the results from the query

Comment: could you please post the full code line that triggered the error ?

Comment: Are you sure something like this isnt working? echo $this->_data[0]->nid;

Comment: Check the edits! I have no idea why this error is happening, as I haven't really changed much of the code since yesterday and yesterday, this exact same thing worked like it's supposed to

Comment: If I move the [0] to the result of the function, it works like it's supposed to. Check the edit at the top of the post. Any idea on why that happens?

Comment: Are you perhaps calling the query multiple times? Perhaps the first call to data() is an empty set and thus $this->_data is empty, where as in the second call $this->_data[0] is set and thus no error occurs

Comment: Nope, it can't be an empty set because of the var_dump output (it's never empty wherever I put that var_dump)

Comment: So you put the var_dump just before the line when the error occurs? Really wierd, Can you do a for loop over it? so: foreach($this->_data as $d) var_dump($d);

Comment: I seem to have narrowed down the problem to the fact that _data is the result from fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ) - which returns multiple objects but NOT inside of an array. It seems that I just need to convert those object results in an array to achieve what I want

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

I've set up a test for this at http://ideone.com/66I3wO - I'm storing your object in an array and I can access $this->_data[0]->nid just fine.

```
<?php

class Test
{
    public $_data = [];

    public function __construct() {
        $this->_data[0] = (object) [
            'uid' => '0',
            'nid' => '374',
            'id' => 'YicnaxYw',
            'txt_content' => null,
            'path' => '/uploads/images/png/YicnaxYw.png',
            'image' => '1',
            'timestamp' => '1448192959',
            'file_ext' => 'png',
            'file_type' => 'image/png',
            'originalFilename' => '2015-11-22_12-49-17.png'
        ];
    }

    public function data(){
        return $this->_data[0];
    }
}

$test = new Test();

echo $test->_data[0]->nid;

var_dump( $test->data() );
```

Comment: Thank you - I've narrowed down the problem to PDO's way of returning multiple objects as an object, rather than as an array of objects

Answer (score 0):

I think the PDO returns an object which is implemented via something like this: http://php.net/manual/en/class.iteratoraggregate.php

When you var_dump it, it will look like an array, but it's not.

You could change your data function to this:

```
function data() {
    foreach($this->_data as $data) {
        return $data;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you explicitly convert to array then you can access the index like you want to:

```
$return = (array) $this->_data;
return $return[0];
```